# Stop bitnami wampstack from automatically running on windows start

Tags: automation, wamp, bitnami

I downloaded Bitnami wampStack.

Usually,when I start my computer,the apache and mysql servers automatically start.

That was a good thing,until I decided to move to XAMPP.

My XAMPP and WAMP apache and myssql servers are meant to be bound to the same ports `80` and `3306` respectively.But when I start my computer,the WAMP servers automatically start and I have to manually turn them off before I can turn on my XAMPP severs or else I will get errors from XAMPP about not being able to bind to port 80 etc.I do not want to entirely delete my wampstack because I may still need it later on for comparison purposes etc I just want to ***stop the WAMP servers from automatically running on system startup but can be turned on manually***.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The Bitnami services are configured to be started automatically on system startup. If you want to modify that, you can simply open the "Services" panel of your machine and modify the properties of the Bitnami services. In the case of WAMP, you will find "wampApache", "wampMySQL", ... or similar services in the list and you will need to set the "Startup Type" to "Manual".

You can find more information about this in our documentation: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/administration/disable-autostart-windows/

Let us know if that works for you.